# How to make a pill shaped TouchableOpacity in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, button, touchableopacity

I currently render my button with margins into a rectangular shape and am wondering how I can round the two sides to create a pill shaped icon. I've tried adding borderRadius to style and it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something really simple that's built into TouchableOpacity?

```
const generateMargins = (direction: FloatDirection): string => {
  // add margin to bottom if the tooltip is in the upper zone
  const bottom = direction.vertical === "upper";
  // add margin to top if the tooltip is in the lower zone
  const top = direction.vertical === "lower";
  // add margin to left if the tooltip is in the Right zone
  const left = direction.horizontal === "right";
  // add margin to right if the tooltip is in the Left zone
  const right = direction.horizontal === "left";
  const margin = {
    top: top ? 20 : 0,
    bottom: bottom ? 20 : 0,
    left: left ? 6 : 0,
    right: right ? 6 : 0
  };
  return `${margin.top}px ${margin.right}px ${margin.bottom}px ${
    margin.right
  }px`;
};

const Box = styled(TouchableOpacity)<IBoxProps>`
  border-color: transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: ${({ direction: { vertical, horizontal } }) =>
    vertical === "lower" && horizontal === "right" ? "0" : borderRadius};
  border-top-right-radius: ${({ direction: { vertical, horizontal } }) =>
    vertical === "lower" && horizontal === "left" ? "0" : borderRadius};
  border-bottom-left-radius: ${({ direction: { vertical, horizontal } }) =>
    vertical === "upper" && horizontal === "right" ? "0" : borderRadius};
  border-bottom-right-radius: ${({ direction: { vertical, horizontal } }) =>
    vertical === "upper" && horizontal === "left" ? "0" : borderRadius};
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px ${colors.translucentGray};
  padding: 7px 8px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: ${({ direction }) => generateMargins(direction)};
  flex-direction: column;
`;
```

Edit: I was indeed missing something - removing the border radius fixed it and allowed the pill shape to work.

Comment: Have you tried setting overflow: hidden; ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Full example here (https://snack.expo.dev/b2B_GsHsZ). Code below. The main idea is to make the height bigger than the width and then add border radius.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{
      flex:1,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"
    }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
            borderWidth:1,
            borderColor:'black',
            alignItems:'center',
            justifyContent:'center',
            width:100,
            height:150,
            backgroundColor:'#fff',
            borderRadius:50,
          }}
      >
            <Entypo name="chevron-right" size={30} color="black" />     
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```